# How to make rsvp through ui?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, ruby-on-rails-5

So, what I want to do is make a Rsvp through a UI. I basically want it so the user can press a button and rsvp for an event(or to a post for this case).It possible to make a rsvp through rails console but I want it so users can individually rsvp for an event without me doing anything from the backend.

**rsvp.rb**

```
class Rsvp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @post.date %>
</p>
<p>where:<%=@post.longitude %>, <%=@post.latitude%></p>

<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User_id:</strong>
  <%= @post.user_id %>
</p>


<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<% if current_user == @post.user %>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%end%>
 <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

 <%= link_to "sign up", posts_url, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
```

So basically the button that goes to posts_url, I want it to be the rsvp button. I would appreciate some help as I'm new to rails and programming in general. Please let me know if you need more code for me to post.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a controller action (with a corresponding route, remember to use a POST verb and not GET). You could use a custom action in the posts controller, but I think you're better off using the create action in the RSVP controller.

Untested pseudocode incoming--

In routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
  post 'rsvp', to: 'rsvps#create', on: :member
end
```

In your rsvp controller:

```
def create
  rsvp = current_user.rsvps.build({post_id: params[:id]})
  if rsvp.save 
  # and so on
```

And in your view:

```
<%= button_to "Sign up", rsvps_post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

You can use the same technique to un-rsvp using the destroy action.

Comment: The action 'rsvp' could not be found for PostsController. I'm getting this error when I press this button to rsvp. Also how would I show the people that already rsvped to the event?

Comment: My mistake, the route was wrong. Like I said, untested pseudocode. 

To answer your second question: @event.users (it's the whole point of setting up activerecord relations)